# "ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to invalid session id: invalid sessio"

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I am using webdriver.io for automation testing but i am getting error ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to invalid session id: invalid session"
and this is my code

```
    describe("Main Page",()=>{
    it("Verify List Items",()=>{
        browser.url("/");
        browser.pause(5000)

        const listExamples = $$("//div[@id='content']//ul/li");//> Double dollar to find all the elements
        expect (listExamples).toBeElementsArrayOfSize(45);
        
        console.log(listExamples);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer actually from  14/04/2021 sync mode will not be supported anymore starting from Node.js v16 due to changes in Chromium. So I just used async and error was solved.

Comment: how can I use async? putting `sync: false` in config file?

Comment: @DonDiego It's more than that; please see https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async

Answer (score 1):

On WebdriverIO official site, I see that it has the guideline about "How to enable/disable sync mode".
Please take a look on this: https://webdriver.io/docs/async-migration